# Insert controller data on html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to print a set of comments from the dishDetailController in blockquote. I've tried but I do not know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. Here is the code.

```
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
                     content must come *after* these tags -->
                <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
                <!-- Bootstrap -->
                <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

                <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->
            </head>

            <body>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-content">
                    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dish">
                        <ul class="media-list">
                            <li class="media">
                                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                                             ng-src="{{dish.image}}" alt="Uthapizza">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                                        <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                                        <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                                    </h2>
                                    <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <h3>Customer Comments</h3>
                        <blockquote>
                            <!--In this blockquote. -->
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script>

                var app = angular.module('confusionApp', []);

                app.controller('dishDetailController', function ($scope) {

                    var dish = {
                        name: 'Uthapizza',
                        image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                        category: 'mains',
                        label: 'Hot',
                        price: '4.99',
                        description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                        comments: [
                            {
                                rating: 5,
                                comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                author: "John Lemon",
                                date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating: 4,
                                comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                author: "Paul McVites",
                                date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating: 3,
                                comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
                                author: "Michael Jaikishan",
                                date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating: 4,
                                comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                author: "Ringo Starry",
                                date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating: 2,
                                comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                author: "25 Cent",
                                date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            }

                        ]
                    };

                    $scope.dish = dish;

                });

            </script>

            </body>

            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('confusionApp', []);

app.controller('dishDetailController', function($scope) {

  var dish = {
    name: 'Uthapizza',
    image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    label: 'Hot',
    price: '4.99',
    description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
    comments: [{
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }

    ]
  };

  $scope.dish = dish;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" ng-app='confusionApp'>
  <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dish">
    <div class="col-xs-12" >
      <ul class="media-list">
        <li class="media">
          <div class="media-left media-middle">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src="dish.image" alt="Uthapizza">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                                        <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                                        <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                                    </h2>
            <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
      <h3>Customer Comments</h3>
      
      <blockquote ng-repeat="com in dish.comments">
        <!--In this blockquote. -->
        {{ com.comment }}
        {{ com.rating }}
        {{ com.author }}
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

The issue you are facing is that the controller is not valid in the blockquote segment.

The div with `ng-controller="dishDetailController as dish"` is being closed before this particular div. 
To overcome this, you can move the segment to the above div.

```
<div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dish">
.
.
.
  <blockquote ng-repeat="com in dish.comments">
    <!--In this blockquote. -->
    {{ com.comment }}
    {{ com.rating }}
    {{ com.author }}
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Here is a working code pen:
http://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/bqzaaK

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<blockquote ng-repeat="item in dish.comments">
      {{item.comment}} - {{item.author}}                  
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should be assigning your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` to the parent container which will wrap your blockquote items, since it will not work from your current setup, and from your markup, I can't see any `ng-app` as well.

**See below:**

```js
var app = angular.module("confusionApp", []);
app.controller("dishDetailController", function ($scope) {
                    var dish = {
                        name: 'Uthapizza',
                        image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                        category: 'mains',
                        label: 'Hot',
                        price: '4.99',
                        description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                        comments: [
                            {
                                rating: 5,
                                comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                author: "John Lemon",
                                date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating: 4,
                                comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                author: "Paul McVites",
                                date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating: 3,
                                comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
                                author: "Michael Jaikishan",
                                date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating: 4,
                                comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                author: "Ringo Starry",
                                date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            },
                            {
                                rating: 2,
                                comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                author: "25 Cent",
                                date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                            }

                        ]
                    };

                    $scope.dish = dish;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-controller="dishDetailController" ng-app="confusionApp">
                <div class="row row-content">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="media-list">
                            <li class="media">
                                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                                             ng-src="{{dish.image}}" alt="Uthapizza">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                                        <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                                        <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                                    </h2>
                                    <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <h3>Customer Comments</h3>
                        <blockquote ng-repeat="item in dish.comments">
                            {{item}}
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add `ng-app` directive to your html code. For example:
`<body ng-app="confusionApp">`.

Then you need to change `ng-controller="dishDetailController as dish"` to the `ng-controller="dishDetailController"`.

You can read more about `ng-controller` directive (and when you have to use `as`) [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).

To print set a set of comments you would use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)